# Receiving “Input string was not in a correct format” error

Tags: c#

I have problem when I try to debug and encounter this error:

> Input string was not in a correct format

Code:

```
List<Int32> ListintNo = DT_ExcludeNo.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x[0].ToString())).ToList();
```

Comment: Whatever is in `x[0]`'s string representation is not an integer...

Comment: so whats the solution will be ? kindly assist thanks

Comment: What is the type of DT_ExcludeNo?

Comment: i declare it like this :

DataTable DT_ExcludeNo = new DataTable();
dataAdapter.Fill(DT_ExcludeNo);

Comment: There's probably over 20 questions with the exact same title. Maybe 5 to 10 times more on Google.

Comment: My guess is x[0].ToString() is not a valid string that could be converted to an int. See the value in x[0]

Comment: hmm so what it gonna be to be change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
    int i = 0;
    List ListintNo = DT_ExcludeNo.AsEnumerable().Where(x => Int32.TryParse(x[0].ToString(), out i)).Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x[0].ToString())).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same as Ricardos, with a simplification (using `num` in the `Select` statement rather than calling `Convert`, since we've already converted the string with the call to `TryParse()`:

```
var num = 0;
var ListintNo = DT_ExcludeNo.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => int.TryParse(x[0], out num))
    .Select(x => num)
    .ToList();
```